# Time Out Issue in iFrame

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, session-timeout

I have one Java based web application. This application has login page where I can login into the application and go to other jsp pages. It has session time out set already in the web.xml file (let's say for 10min).

In one of the jsp page,  I am showing BI report in iFrame. Now what is happening is, when I am working in BI report under iFrame for more than 10 minutes , I am getting time out message after 10 minutes., because page is not considering iFrame action as it's action, so getting time out message.

Please let me know if you have any idea or solution to ignore time out while working inside iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

well you could add a javascript listener on the i-frame in order to handle the user's action when he is only active inside the i-frame
check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-click-event-handler-to-iframe) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213639/session-logout-page-issue-in-iframe-using-jsp-servlet)